# How to get PPID with PS using BSD options

Tags: linux, process, ps

I'm looking for a ps string that will give me all the output headers of 
"ps aux" but with the PPID. So far, I can only get the PPID column using ps -ef. I have tried numerous combinations but have not been able to find one that accomplishes my goal. Can this be done?

Comment: Why are you limiting it to BSD options?

Comment: Because I have not found the "-ef" equivalent that will (1) - Give me both %CPU and %RAM, and (2) Also provide me with the PPID.

Comment: Then it's not _really_ "using BSD options" that you want :)

Comment: Who keeps down-voting this question? Seriously? Nut the hell up and tell me why you think its "unclear" or "not useful". I have spent hours trying to figure this out ON MY OWN!

Answer (score 4):

Now that we know what you *really* want...

Use `-o` to select your desired fields. For instance:

```
$ ps -eo pid,ppid,%cpu,%mem,args
  PID  PPID %CPU %MEM COMMAND
    1     0  0.0  0.0 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 22
...more procs...
 1522  3205  0.0  0.0 nginx: worker process
 1523  3205  0.0  0.0 nginx: worker process
 1525  3205  0.0  0.0 nginx: worker process
 1527  3205  0.0  0.0 nginx: worker process
 1528  3205  0.0  0.0 nginx: worker process
 1529  3205  0.0  0.0 nginx: worker process
 3205     1  0.0  0.0 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx
...more procs...
```

A complete list of the fields you can use is in the man page.

Comment: Thanks Michael, but I don't want to have to specify every field I want in the command to get the output I want. Maybe I was not clear enough in my original description. For instance using unix98 options I wish to have the output of "ps -eFlj --forest" but with the addition of the %CPU and %MEM columns, without having to build everything out. I thought this would be simple :(

Comment: If you want something a specific way, you have to specify it yourself.

Comment: Specifics is not what I'm after. For example, I am happy with the default full format listing of aux or -ef, in the order its provided. I am simply wanting to add columns to an already "specified" output. :)

Comment: Then specifics _are_ what you're after. Here is a simple, easy solution! Decide what you want and ask for it. I did not write `ps` so it won't do any good to argue with me. I can't change its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps options "-l" or "-j"? (Depending on the version of your "ps") https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ps(1)

Comment: No luck. I can use the -j but that will only add PGID and SID. I am specifically looking for the PPID. I wonder of there is a way to use the standard -ef instead of BSD's aux and just add a switch to that to give me aux-like output? I will keep searching. BTW - who down voted this anyway? This is a legitimate question.

Comment: I didn't downvote, as I've struggled with 'ps' portability in the past as well (it's not, at all; makes cross-platform shell scripting challenging). But it is a type of 'rtfm' about it. Perhaps state your exact OS, version, the command you tried, and how the output differed from the expected as per the man page...?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution (if anyone still needs it). On RHEL/CentOS and derived, try `# ps -fwaux`: it shows you all the processes, but lists the childs under their parents; in that way you shouldn't need the PPID column to relate a process to its origin. I hope that's gonna be useful... cheers!